# How to find the coordinates of the outside corners of these 4 squares? (morphological closing/opening does not conserve squares if image is rotated)

Tags: python, image-processing, opencv, image-morphology

One of the first processing steps in a tool I'm coding is to **find the coordinates of the outside corners of 4 big black squares**. They will then be used to do a homographic transform, in order to deskew / unrotate the image (a.k.a perspective transform), to finally get a rectangular image. Here is an example of - rotated and noisy - input ([download link here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qErnm.jpg)):

[image]

To keep the big squares only, I'm using [morphological transformations](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html) like closing/opening:

```
import cv2, numpy as np
img = cv2.imread('rotatednoisy-cropped.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
kernel = np.ones((30, 30), np.uint8)
img = cv2.morphologyEx(img, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, kernel)
cv2.imwrite('output.png', img)
```

Input file ([download link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8Nya.jpg)):

[image]

Output, after morphological transform:

[image]

Problem: the output squares are not square anymore, and therefore *the coordinates of the top left corner of the square will be not precise at all*!

I could reduce the kernel size, but then it would keep more unwanted small elements.

**Question: how to get a better detection of the corners of the squares?**

---

Note:

- As a [morphological closing](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_morphological_ops/py_morphological_ops.html#closing) is just a dilatation + an erosion, I found the culprit:

  ```
  import cv2, numpy as np
  img = cv2.imread('rotatednoisy-cropped.png', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
  kernel = np.ones((30, 30), np.uint8)
  img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations = 1)
  ```

  After this step, it's still ok:

  [image]

  Then

  ```
  img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations = 1)
  ```

  gives

  [image]

  and it's not ok anymore!

Comment: Why not use `cv2.findContours()` and choose 4 biggest ones?

Comment: @Georgy: I have other zones in the image that might have long contours (btw, what do you consider the "biggest"? is it perimeter? area?). Could you post an answer with it? Thank you in advance (I have already read the doc about it, but everytimes I use opencv and image processing, the devil is in the details ;) to get a usable/good precision).

Comment: If there may be other long contours, then maybe you would need to [detect square shapes](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection/) among them. (I'm not an OpenCV expert myself. I used `findContours` couple of times, and your case looked like something where it could be used.)

Comment: Try using a closing by reconstruction.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I don't know this, can you post an answer, also showing how to get the coordinates of the corners?

Comment: PS: I just discovered [Abid Rahman K's blog](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/sudoku-solver-part-2.html) and it's really really awesome to see python opencv in action, see [why adaptative thresholding is better than standard](http://opencvpython.blogspot.com/2012/06/some-common-questions.html), etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [this link](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/02/20/text-skew-correction-opencv-python/) for detailed explanation on how to de-skew an image.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

def corners(box):
    cx,cy,w,h,angle = box[0][0],box[0][1],box[1][0],box[1][1],box[2]
    CV_PI = 22./7.
    _angle = angle*CV_PI/180.;
    b = np.cos(_angle)*0.5;
    a = np.sin(_angle)*0.5;

    pt = []
    pt.append((int(cx - a*h - b*w),int(cy + b*h - a*w)));
    pt.append((int(cx + a*h - b*w),int(cy - b*h - a*w)));
    pt.append((int(2*cx - pt[0][0]),int(2*cy - pt[0][1])));
    pt.append((int(2*cx - pt[1][0]),int(2*cy - pt[1][1])));
    return pt

if __name__ == '__main__':

    image = cv2.imread('image.jpg',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    n = 3
    sigma = 0.3 * (n/2 - 1) + 0.8
    gray = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, ksize=(n,n), sigmaX=sigma)

    ret,binary = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    _,contours,_ = cv2.findContours(binary, cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

    contours.sort(key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)

    points = []
    for i in range(0,4):
        shape = cv2.approxPolyDP(contours[i], 0.05*cv2.arcLength(contours[i],True), True)
        if len(shape) == 4:
            points.append(shape)

    points = np.array(points,dtype=np.int32)
    points = np.reshape(points, (-1,2))
    box = cv2.minAreaRect(points)
    pt = corners(box)

    for i in range(0,4):
       image = cv2.line(image, (pt[i][0],pt[i][1]), (pt[(i+1)%4][0],pt[(i+1)%4][1]), (0,0,255))


    (h,w) = image.shape[:2]
    (center) = (w//2,h//2)
    angle = box[2]

    if angle < -45:
        angle = (angle+90)
    else:
        angle = -angle

    M = cv2.getRotationMatrix2D(center, angle, 1.0)
    rotated = cv2.warpAffine(image, M, (w,h), flags=cv2.INTER_CUBIC, borderMode=cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT)

    cv2.imshow('image', image)
    cv2.imshow('rotated', rotated)
    cv2.waitKey(0)
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image] [image: result]

Comment: Thank you very much! It works wonderfully! Can you just add the line of code that draws the red rectangle (for completeness)?

Comment: Are we sure that the 4 contours with longest length (i.e. highest number of points) are necessarily the 4 squares? (I'm not sure). I suggest a little modification: `contours.sort(key=lambda c: cv2.contourArea(c), reverse=True)` and use `for i in range(1,5):` (the contour with biggest area is the full image, so we start at contours[1] to contours[4]). What is your opinion about that @zindarod?

Comment: @Basj See edit for line drawing code. As to sorting contours, it depends on the type of image and thresholding results. I am sorting based on number of contour points and shape of contour. You can define your own criteria.

Comment: I noticed that the OTSU thresholding is great (I tried with a standard thresholding, non OTSU, it's a lot worse!), `cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_OTSU+cv2.THRESH_BINARY)` is very important! Thanks for this important concept!

Comment: @zindarod I tried your code for another input with different directions of rotation, but the result is more rotated instead of perpendicular position. Am I missing something?
(it is works well with your sample image in that direction of rotation)

Answer (score 2):

You could try by searching and filtering out your specific contours (black rectangles) and sorting them with a key. Then select the extreme point for each contour (left, right, top, bottom) and you will get the points. Note that this approach is ok for this picture only and if the picture was roteted in other direction, you would have to change the code accordingly. I am not an expert but I hope this helps a bit.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2


img = cv2.imread("rotate.jpg")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
ret, threshold = cv2.threshold(gray,150,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
im, contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(threshold,cv2.RETR_TREE,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
contours.sort(key=lambda c: np.min(c[:,:,1]))
j = 1

if len(contours) > 0:
    for i in range(0, len(contours)):
        size = cv2.contourArea(contours[i])
        if 90 < size < 140:
            if j == 1:
                c1 = contours[i]
                j += 1
            elif j == 2:
                c2 = contours[i]
                j += 1
            elif j == 3:
                c3 = contours[i]
                j += 1
            elif j == 4:
                c4 = contours[i]
                break

Top = tuple(c1[c1[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
Right = tuple(c2[c2[:, :, 0].argmax()][0])
Left = tuple(c3[c3[:, :, 0].argmin()][0])
Bottom = tuple(c4[c4[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])

cv2.circle(img, Top, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, Right, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, Left, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)
cv2.circle(img, Bottom, 2, (0, 255, 0), -1)

cv2.imshow("Image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Maybe even better approach would be to assign Left, Right, Top and Bottom position by selecting Top for highest y coordinate in points (c1, c2, c3, c4), Bottom for lowest y coordinate, Left for lowest x coordinate and Right for highest x coordinate. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the squares as single blobs after binarization with a suitable threshold, and select the appropriate ones based on size. You can also first denoise with a median filter if you want.

Then a tight rotated bounding rectangle will give you the corners (you can obtain it by running Rotating Calipers on the Convex Hull).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What do you mean exactly by `single blobs after binarization`?Tthe median filtering denoising part + thresholding to get a black/white picture is no problem; by the way, you can assume the image is already black+white only, with no noise at all.

Comment: If you have a few minutes @YvesDaoust, could you add some code to show the algorithm you describe? There seems to be many possibilities to do it, and in order to see if it works 99%, 99,999% or only 80% of the time, some code would be very helpful (also for future reference / future readers). Thank you in advance.

Comment: @Basj: sorry, no, I am just explaining the principle. Blob analysis will detect several blobs and you need to consider the ones with the size of a square. If there is no noise and the given image is representative, this will be bulletproof. To find the corners, I suggested a bounding box. But looking for the extreme points in the four diagonal directions can work as well.