# How to identity straight lines from a list of rectangles

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

My goal is to identify 4 intersected points and do perspective transform.

Given a list of computed rectangles `[x, y, w, h]` (derived from contours), how to find 4 best lines of a paper.

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34981144/split-text-lines-in-scanned-document) uses `minAreaRect` to find the area of non-white pixels but in my case, the environment is very noisy and it is not possible to eliminate all white points even with extensive image processing algorithms applied.

Here is my processing pipeline

- Grayscale and binarize
- Apply morphological operations to remove unlikely characters
- Find contours with a set of rules (experimented values)

I am now thinking a way to get 4 intersected points by first finding 4 lines (left, top, right and bottom) and then do deskew.

Is this something possible?

[Link to original Image](https://ibb.co/kyb0n3y)

[image: Contours]

The ideal result would be something like this, which four points can be identified.

[image]

**Update 1**

Attempting to convert a list of rectangles to points. I can only work with rectangles at this stage because previous operations no longer return contours.

```
def rectsToPoints(rects):

    points = []

    for x1, y1, x2, y2 in rects:
        x, y, w, h = x1, y1, x2-x1, y2-y1

        points.append([
            (x, y),
            (x+w, y),
            (x, y+h),
            (x+w, y+h)
        ])

    return np.array(points, dtype=np.int32)

points = rectsToPoints(rects)
minRect = cv2.minAreaRect(points)
```

**Type Error**

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.3) /Users/travis/build/skvark/opencv-python/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/convhull.cpp:137: error: (-215:Assertion failed) total >= 0 && (depth == CV_32F || depth == CV_32S) in function 'convexHull'
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50914972/2286337).

Comment: Put the four vertices of each rectangle in a list of points, and use `minAreaRect`

Comment: @Miki Let me try, is there an order I need to follow for the 4 points?

Comment: @zindarod That answer you shared is nice! It uses the 4 largest contours as reference point right? But in my example I have no way to extract that four relevant contour

Comment: @RexLow no need to order the points

Comment: @Miki I've updated my post with a function I made to convert rects to points. However, it seems like I am getting a type error. I can only use rects at the moment because previous operations no longer return contours.